に marking passive verb?
I noticed something in a song title I was unfamiliar with and haven't been able to figure out how to interpret it:
抱かれにきた女－濱田 金吾
Specifically 抱かれに, this appears to be 抱く in passive form, but it doesn't have it's ending る. I know that passive verbs and に naturally go together, but with に marking who the action was done by. In this situation it's marking a verb?

Have you heard about [Continuative (連用形) Form of Verb + に + Verb of Motion (e.g. 行く, 来る)] construction? E.g. this answer. There is a separate Continuative form for Active, Passive, Causative, Causative Passive (and for some archaic grammatical constructions): 抱き ("hugging"), 抱かれ ("being hugged"), 抱かせ ("making (somebody) hug (somebody)"), 抱かせられ ("making (somebody) being hugged").

Ah yes, I am familiar but I don't think I've ever seen an example with くる or it being used with a verb in any form other than dictionary. I've looked up a translation but what this really means is "a woman whose REASON for coming is to be hugged" right?

Yes, this is correct translation.

Thank you so much for your help! If you want to submit a full answer I'll mark it as correct.

I'm sure it will involve much more than hugging...

Continuative (連用形) Form of Verb + に + Verb of Motion (e.g. 行く, 来る) construction means "to go/come somewhere to do something".
Technically each verb has not only 1 Continuative (連用形) form, 1 Conclusive (終止形) form, 1 Attributive (連体形) form, 1 -te form, but many forms, for each combination of voice and aspect and some other constructions.
Continuative (連用形) form is created by attaching -i suffix to stem for consonant-stem verbs, and by using bare stem for vowel-stem verbs.
-te form (sometimes called Conjunctive or Gerund) was originally regularly created by attaching suffix -te to Continuative (連用形) form of all verbs. In Late Middle Japanese, some phonological changes occurred for formation of this form for consonant-stem verbs (…k-i-te → …-i-te, …g-i-te → …-i-de, …m-i-te → …n-de, …b-i-te → …n-de, …n-i-te → …n-de, …t-i-te → …t-te, …r-i-te → …t-te, OJ …Vp-i-te → EMJ …Vw-i-te → …V-i-te → …Vt-te).

Examples for consonant-stem verb dak-:

"basic" Continuative (連用形): dak-i

"basic" -te form: da-i-te (in Early Middle Japanese: dak-i-te)

"basic" Conclusive (終止形): dak-u

"basic" Attributive (連体形): dak-u

Potential Continuative (連用形): dak-e

Potential -te form: dak-e-te

Potential Conclusive (終止形): dak-e-ru (in Late Middle Japanese, if original Conclusive (終止形) still existed: dak-u)

Potential Attributive (連体形): dak-e-ru (in Late Middle Japanese, if this suffix still was in nidan class: dak-uru)
(Potential forms with suffix -e did not exist yet in Old / Early Middle Japanese.)

Passive Continuative (連用形): dak-are

Passive -te form: dak-are-te

Passive Conclusive (終止形): dak-are-ru (in Early Middle Japanese: dak-ar-u)

Passive Attributive (連体形): dak-are-ru (in Middle Japanese: dak-ar-uru)

Causative Continuative (連用形): dak-ase

Causative -te form: dak-ase-te

Causative Conclusive (終止形): dak-ase-ru (in Early Middle Japanese: dak-as-u)

Causative Attributive (連体形): dak-ase-ru (in Middle Japanese: dak-as-uru)

Causative Passive Continuative (連用形): dak-ase-rare

Causative Passive -te form: dak-ase-rare-te

Causative Passive Conclusive (終止形): dak-ase-rare-ru (in Early Middle Japanese: dak-ase-rar-u)

Causative Passive Attributive (連体形): dak-ase-rare-ru (in Middle Japanese: dak-ase-rar-uru)

Old / Early Middle Japanese -te- Perfective Continuative (連用形): mudak-i-te

Old / Early Middle Japanese -te- Perfective -te form: mudak-i-te-te

Old / Early Middle Japanese -te- Perfective Conclusive (終止形): mudak-i-t-u

Old / Early Middle Japanese -te- Perfective Attributive (連体形): mudak-i-t-uru


(-te form and -te- Perfective (used primarily for transitive verbs) (conjugating as e-vowel-stem) are unrelated according to linguists such as Frellesvig and Vovin. There was also -ni- Perfective (used primarily for intransitive verbs) (conjugating as i-vowel-stem), whose -te form was -ni-te. Mixing of 2 perfectives is not attested, but their -te forms, -te-te and -ni-te, are attested, which is good argument for -te form and -te- Perfective being unrelated. -te- Perfective and -ni- Perfective died out after Early Middle Japanese.)
(Uses of Attributive (連体形) form in conclusive (predicative) function are attested in small numbers already since Old Japanese, and increasingly in Early Middle Japanese. In approximately first half (1200 - 1400) of Late Middle Japanese (1200 - 1600), original form of Conclusive (終止形) died out for all verbs and adjectives (except things like 〜べし, 〜まじ), and Attributive (連体形) took over syntactic functions (predicate in main clauses) of Conclusive (終止形).)

dak- is attested since about 999 (Early Middle Japanese). The only form of stem of this verb attested in Old Japanese is mudak-. Development was:
mudak- → ũdak- → udak- → idak- → dak-
